# I want to get the version number of Power-BI from the website and the -match is true but I can not see the version number, how I can see the number?

Tags: powershell, match, invoke-webrequest

```
 $Uri = 'https://aka.ms/pbiSingleInstaller'
   $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri 
   $url=$web.Links |Where-Object href -Like "*confirmation*" | Select-Object -expand href 
 ( $downloadurlid = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/" + $url )
   $idcontent = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadurlid 
 ( $downloadurl = $idcontent.Links |Where-Object href -Like "*x64.exe" | Select-Object -First 1 -expand href )
   $a = $web.Content
(  $a -match "\d*.\d*.\d*.\d* " )
 ( $latestversion = "$($Matches[1])")
 ( $FileName = $downloadurl.Split('/')[-1])
```

here is my script I want to get the version number which is here(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494) like Version:

2.110.1161.0 , the match returns true but I can not see the result
can someone help me how I can get the version number? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex `\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*`  is a problem here. `\d*.` matches 0 or more digits followd by any character, so full regex matches any three characters before space, even if there were no digits.
First tag in `$web.Content` was `<!DOCTYPE html >`, so `$Matches` now contains `YPE` .

Try `$web.Content -match 'd\+.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'`. `\d+` means at least one digit, and `\.` a dot (`.` without escape `\` means any character).
It now finds version number, but please note that using regex to parse html document can yield incorrect results if page content changes in the future. It'd be safer to use xPath for that.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, but if I use `-match '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'` it returns true but still does not show the version when I run `( $latestversion = "$($Matches[1])")` or if I use  `-match 'd\+.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'` as you said it returns false .

Comment: @atefehkasiri It's because you're checking `$Matches[1]`, but you have not specified capture group in regex. Try `$Matches[0]` or use regex `'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'` to have it in `$Matches[1]`.